# Sticky Headers in Sharepint 2019

Tags: sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

Does anyone know if sticky headers are going to be a standard in SP 2019 on Prem? It seems they are slowly rolling it out for the on-line version. [January 2019 SharePoint Modernization News](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/January-2019-SharePoint-Modernization-News/bc-p/744631#M3991)

Comment: At some most probably, from what I understand general goal is to keep both SP on prem and online on same code base where possible. But don't expect it soon. New features will be not be released to on prem as online.